# Error to save a new medico in the database

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this problem when saving a new doctor in the database using Angular, this is the error

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Zdq.png)

this is my code in medico Component

```
 guardarMedico() {
    const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value
    console.log(this.medicoForm.value)
    this.medicoService.crearMedico(this.medicoForm.value)
      .subscribe((resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp);
        Swal.fire('Creado', `${nombre} registrado correctamente`, 'success');
        this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/medico/${resp.msg._id}`)
      })

  }
```

This is the code for medico services

```
  crearMedico(medico: { nombre: string, hospital: string }) {

    const url = `${base_url}/medicos`;
    return this.http.post(url, medico, this.headers);


  }
```

this is ny code in backend

```
const crearMedico = async (req, res = response) => {

    const uid = req.uid;
    const medico = new Medico({
        administrador: uid,
        ...req.body
    });


    try {

        const medicoDB = await medico.save();

        res.json({
            ok: true,
            medico: medicoDB
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: "Error Consule con el administrador"
        })

    }

}
```

I try change this part

```
 guardarMedico() {
    const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value
    console.log(this.medicoForm.value)
    this.medicoService.crearMedico(this.medicoForm.value)
      .subscribe((resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp);
        Swal.fire('Creado', `${nombre} registrado correctamente`, 'success');
        this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/medico/${resp.**msg**._id}`)
      })

  }
```

For this part

```
 guardarMedico() {
    const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value
    console.log(this.medicoForm.value)
    this.medicoService.crearMedico(this.medicoForm.value)
      .subscribe((resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp);
        Swal.fire('Creado', `${nombre} registrado correctamente`, 'success');
        this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/medico/${resp.**medico**._id}`)
      })

  }
```

Making this change allows you to store a new medico, but when you save another doctor again, the problem jumps.

So it only lets you store 1 new doctor my idea is that it does not create a new uid for a second doctor

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv1Mk.png)

this is the Schema

```
const MedicoSchema = Schema({

    nombre: {
        type: String,
        require: true

    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },

    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    administrador: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Administrador',
        required: true
    },
    hospital: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Hospital',
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'medico',
    }

});
```

This is the error on console

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: GesAstur.medicos index: email_1 dup key: { email: null }
    at C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:53:33
    at C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:299:25
    at C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:212:17
    at handleOperationResult (C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:287:20)
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:219:9)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:60:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:132:20)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Angular-adv\Repositorio\04-backend-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12) {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { email: 1 },
  keyValue: { email: null },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you include the schema you are trying to enforce (basically pasting the code of `Medico` on backend side)? Can you also paste the error that was logged in the backend?

Comment: the database i use is mongo DB and the error is written by me in the controller. If you need more parts of the code please ask me to update it

Comment: I am talking about the error, that was thrown on backend side. You just reposted the error, that was logged on frontend side. Are you using the same email for the second request? I assume that the `unique` flag is rejecting the second entry with the same email.

Comment: Ok I think I understand you in the postman when I create a medico I have to enter an email.

but of course in the front I don't send any email, I'm going to try to remove the email flag to see if that's why,
or ask him for an email in the front and maybe he will solve the error for me

Comment: Yes, you should reconsider your Schema. You pass `require` property, which should be `required`. This way not sending an email would also result in an error, but of course an error is thrown if your payload does not match the expected Schema.

Comment: ok I will update it and I will remove the required one and the only one I download and update it and I will tell you if it worked or not thank you very much

Comment: Fixed error. It was a problem of what the partner said and the required email.

Thank you very much